Retrieve template based emails and their associated templates using the Content Builder API
I'm trying to retrieve emails and their associated templates using the Content Builder API. In Postman, I can find the template name field, but I can't access it using SSJS. Does anyone know how this can be done?
This is the code I'm using:
<script runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    var accessToken; // Define accessToken variable outside try block
    var restInstanceUrl = "https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/"; // Define restInstanceUrl

    try {
        // Config
        var authUrl = "https://{{et_subdomain}}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com";
        var clientId = "";
        var clientSecret = "";

        var result = HTTP.Post(authUrl + "/v2/token", 'application/json', Stringify({
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            "client_id": clientId,
            "client_secret": clientSecret,
            "account_id":"" 
        }));

        if (result.StatusCode == 200) {
            var responseJson = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0]);
            accessToken = responseJson.access_token; // Assign value to accessToken
        } else {
            throw "Failed to obtain access token. StatusCode: " + result.StatusCode;
        }

    } catch (error) {
        Write('Authentication error: ' + error);
    }

    try {
        var payload = {
            page: {
                page: 1,
                pageSize: 50
            },
            query: {
                property: "assetType.id",
                simpleOperator: "IN",
                value: ["207"]
            },
            sort: [
                {
                    property: "id",
                    direction: "ASC"
                }
            ]
        }

        var endpoint = restInstanceUrl + "asset/v1/content/assets/query";

        var request = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(endpoint);
        request.emptyContentHandling = 0;
        request.retries = 2;
        request.continueOnError = true;
        request.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        request.method = "POST";
        request.contentType = "application/json";
        request.postData = Stringify(payload);

        var results = request.send();

        var result = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(results.content));

        var items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++) {
            var asset = result.items[i];
            items.push({
                name: asset.name,
                templateName: asset.content.template.name
            });
        }

        Write(Stringify(items));
    } catch(error) {
        Write(Stringify(error));
    } 

</script>


Add these lines and try it  var templateName = asset.content && asset.content.template ? asset.content.template.name : "No Template";
        items.push({

            name: asset.name,

            templateName: templateName

